# How can I send data from a JSON into a constante variable using Node Fetch? TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-fetch

I'm working in a NodeJS project, and I'm expecting to take data from a JSON and then send it into my `app2.mjs` to a constant variable, to then send them into an array of objects to after that save it into a DB, the issue I'm having is that I send this data this way:

```
const info = await fetch("./json/data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });
```

and I get this message error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at onParseError (node:internal/url:552:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:628:5)
    at new Request (file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/X/node_modules/node-fetch/src/request.js:51:16)
    at file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/X/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:38:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:36:9)
    at calcWeather (file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/X/app2.mjs:39:22)
    at executeStatement (file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/X/app2.mjs:75:3)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (file:///X:/X/X/X/X/X/X/X/app2.mjs:29:5) {
  input: './json/data.json',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
```

I'm using `"node-fetch": "^3.1.0",` to load the JSON, here is my `data.json` (juts a few, cause I have like a hundred data)

```
[
  [
    {
      "latjson": 0,
      "lonjson": 0,
      "IdOficina": "0",
      "NombreOficinaSN": "X",
      "Zona": "X",
      "NombreEstado": "X"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "latjson": 1,
      "lonjson": 1,
      "IdOficina": "1",
      "NombreOficinaSN": "Y",
      "Zona": "Y",
      "NombreEstado": "Y"
    }
  ]
]
```

and here's the part where I do the fetch

```
async function calcWeather() {
  const info = await fetch("./json/data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });
  console.log(info)
  for (var i in info) {
    
    const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina;
    const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
    const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
    const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    fetch(base)
      .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var myObject = {
          Id_Oficina: _idOficina,
          Humedad: data.main.humidity,
          Nubes: data.clouds.all,
          Sensacion: data.main.feels_like,
          Temperatura: data.main.temp,
          Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
        };
        // validation and saving data to array
        if (myObject.Temperatura < 99) {
          lstValid.push(myObject);
        }
      });
  }
  console.log(lstValid);
}
```

I add here below the way my project is structured, any help is welcomed:

[image]

Comment: From node, `"./json/data.json"` is a relative path to your local machine,  as such you don't use fetch, as that's for `http/s` requests, use `readFile` instead.

Comment: `fetch` makes HTTP calls. If you want to read a file, use Node's built-in fs (file system) module. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions

Answer (score 0):

Thing is as you are fetching it from local, first You have to make your local a server. Like you can add your js file throgh script tag in a html page and there you can open it with live server and in the  browser's console   you can check whether it is fetching or not. If  the json file's relative url is right then it will fetch.